DAG parallel tasks - running more than two in parallel
I'm using Google Composer to orchestration my jobs and created a DAG using BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator, that will create a job on Google Dataflow. When I make a DAG with 2 tasks in paralel, work's fine, but when I put more than 2 tasks in paralel, DAG stuck on running state and doesn't create any job on Dataflow.
I already increase scheduler and excutor resources, but behavior is the same. What I need to do to DAG to create more than 2 tasks in paralel?
